# Send complex command to API using the & argument

Tags: python

I have to send commands to an API using Python.
The API's documentation was written to send receive CURL commands.

I converted the curl string

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer accesstoken" https://www.website.com/feed.php?command=COMMAND
```

Into this:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer accesstoken',
}
params = {
    'command': "COMMAND",
}
response = requests.get('https://www.website.com/feed.php', params=params, headers=headers)
```

The problem is if the command I want to send is a complex command like:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer accesstoken" https://www.website.com/feed.php?command=COMMAND&wake=10
```

the conversion to Python won't work as this "&wake=10" isn't accepted.

Any ideas on how to circumvent this?

Comment: You need to explain why you think "&wake=10" isn't accepted and any errors you're getting.  The python `requests` library accepts query parameters https://realpython.com/python-requests/#query-string-parameters

Comment: try using raw strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple query parameters in the `params` dictionary - requests will turn them into the required URL format.

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer accesstoken',
}
params = {
   'command': "COMMAND",
   'wake': 10
}
response = requests.get('https://www.website.com/feed.php', params=params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: wake is also a command, therefore we would need something like "command": "wake=10". am I interpreting this well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split on the `&`, resulting in multiple key + value pairs in `params`.

```
params = {
    "command": "COMMAND",
    "wake": "10"
}
```